# SDL_mixer stop playing music on certain event

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-mixer

My program needs to stop playing sound if certain point is in range, for that I have class with function `run()` which runs on seperate thread and plays sound using `SDL.h` and `SDL_mixer.h`:

```
void SoundCheck::run()
{
    Mix_PlayMusic(music, 1);
    while(1)
    {
        if(normalize(sound[0], range_->getPos()))
        {

            printf("stop sound\n");
            Mix_HaltChannel(-1);
        }
        sleep(1);

    }
}
```

but when `if` condition returns true it prints "stop sound" but sound still plays, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

`Mix_HaltChannel` is used to stop a `Mix_Chunk` after being started with `Mix_PlayChannel`.

To stop a `Mix_Music` after being started with `Mix_PlayMusic`, you must use `Mix_HaltMusic`.