# How to Halt Sound Effect in SDL2

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

How would I halt the playing of a sound effect in SDL2?

Currently I'm playing sound effects using the SDL2 Mixer with this code.

```
Mix_PlayChannel(-1, soundEffect, 0);
```

However I want the play to be able to not have to listen to the entire sound effect and when they leave the menu the sound effect should stop.

I've tried `Mix_HaltMusic();` however that doesn't seem to apply to `Mix_Chunk`.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the `Mix_Chunk` started with `Mix_PlayChannel`, you have to use `Mix_HaltChannel` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923391/5156280) for the opposite problem.